# Twitter APIs Error Python: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, twitterapi-python

So, I wrote a code for a Twitter Bot that tweets "YES" on every thursday. However, when i run the code i get the following error:

> 403 Forbidden
> 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

This is the code that i wrote

```
import tweepy
import datetime
import time

consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def is_giovedi():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A') == 'Thursday'

def post_tweet():
    if is_giovedi():
        tweet = "SI"
    else:
        tweet = "NO"

    api.update_status(status=tweet)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    target_time = now.replace(hour=12, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    
    if now < target_time:
        time_to_wait = (target_time - now).seconds
        print(f"Aspetto {time_to_wait} secondi")
        time.sleep(time_to_wait)

    post_tweet()
    print("Tweet inviato con successo!")
```

Hope someone can help me

I put the keys that the code asked me from the twitter developer portal, but when i run the code it gives me this error

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you tried to call the **Twitter API v1.1**, which can only be used for **Media Uploads**.

For **posting a tweet**, you should call the **Twitter API v2**.

Replace:

```py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

with the following code snippet:

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)
```

And, also replace:

```py
api.update_status(status=tweet)
```

with the following code snippet:

```py
# Post Tweet
client.create_tweet(text=tweet)
```

For more information on **Twitter API v2**:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.14.0/client.html#

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can create tweets now from this client.create_tweet(text=tweet). but how can I upload a video along with tweet. Can you please share that endpoint also?

Comment: @AnkitKumar Refer [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/overview](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/overview)